# Why doesnt the Power BI iFrame report display properly? (In Javafx)

Tags: iframe, javafx, powerbi

im trying to embed a PowerBI iFrame, however the reports are not displaying I just see a white space, while when I browse the same URL in my browser, the reports are visible. Every other webpage though is showing properly in my app. This is what I have so far:

```
  WebView webView = new WebView();
    WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
     webEngine.loadContent(content_Url);
```

while content_Url is :

```
String content_Url = "<iframe width=\"900\" height=\"656\" src=\"https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiMzdiNGIzOWMtOGFiMi00YTc0LWFhYmYtZjcyN2E3YzljYTY1IiwidCI6IjQzY2Q3MWNlLTBjODYtNGMxZi05NTc1LTBlMzg4YWEwZDY4YiIsImMiOjh9\" frameborder=\"0\" allowFullScreen=\"true\" action=\"embedview\"  wdbipreview=\"true\"></iframe>";
```

I have tried it another way:

```
 WebView webView = new WebView();
WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
 webEngine.load(https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiMzdiNGIzOWMtOGFiMi00YTc0LWFhYmYtZjcyN2E3YzljYTY1IiwidCI6IjQzY2Q3MWNlLTBjODYtNGMxZi05NTc1LTBlMzg4YWEwZDY4YiIsImMiOjh9);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.. the PowerBI embedded is not supported in the WebView browser.( http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Why-is-my-report-empty-when-embedded-in-JavaFX-app/m-p/92546#M3283 )